# PHP how to find array value from string post

Tags: php, codeigniter

Using PHP & codeigniter. 
I posting below to my PHP api 
submitting from front end - > `{"academicYear":"2015","subjectClassification":"Primary","subjectId":"55","teacherId":[10,16,17]}`

**I need to find or print teacherId values in my PHP code.
Basically my target is to print "HELLO" 3 time if there is 3 Id in `teacherId` array.**

My code look like below,

```
function subjectTeacherAllocation_post(){
        $data = remove_unknown_fields($this->post() ,$this->form_validation->get_field_names('subjectTeacherAllocation_post'));
        $this->form_validation->set_data($data);

        var_dump($data);

        $teacherList = array($data['teacherId']);
        echo $teacherList[0];
        echo array_values($teacherList);
```

var_dump output --> `array(3) { ["academicYear"]=> string(4) "2014" ["subjectId"]=> string(2) "55" ["teacherId"]=> array(3) { [0]=> int(9) [1]=> int(15) [2]=> int(32) } }`

Comment: what is the output you are getting for ```echo $teacherList[0];``` and ```echo array_values($teacherList);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are needlessly wrapping `$data['teacherId']` in an extra array, instead just do:

```
$teacherList = $data['teacherId'];
echo $teacherList[0]; //9
```

Specifically, to produce hello x number of times, where x is the number of elements in the above `$teacherList` array:

```
foreach($teacherList as $unused){
    echo 'hello';
}
```